# ROBOT FRAMEWORK [ ERROR ] Parsing 'TC2.robot' failed: File or directory to execute does not exist

Tags: compiler-errors, robotframework

I try to run my robot framework but it was failed. Can anybody tell me about these case?
there is always this sign

"[ ERROR ] Parsing 'TC2.robot' failed: File or directory to execute does not exist.

Try --help for usage information. "

Comment: Please provide more information - what is the command you're running, where are you running it from? What is the dir structure?